# Unesting dictionaries in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame df1 with the following structure:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'campaign_name': ['Campanha A'],
    'date_start': ['2022-01-01'],
    'date_stop': ['2022-01-31'],
    'reach': [1060],
    'impressions': [2040],
    'clicks': [72],
    'amount_spent': [79.32],
    'cpc': [1.10],
    'ctr': [3.53],
    'actions': [
        [{'action_type': 'post', 'value': '4'}, {'action_type': 'post_engagement', 'value': '3'}, {'action_type': 'post_reaction', 'value': '1'}]
    ]
})
```

I would like to transform this DataFrame into the following format:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'campaign_name': ['Campanha A'],
    'date_start': ['2022-01-01'],
    'date_stop': ['2022-01-31'],
    'reach': [1060],
    'impressions': [2040],
    'clicks': [72],
    'amount_spent': [79.32],
    'cpc': [1.10],
    'ctr': [3.53],
    'post': 4,
    'post_engagement': 3,
    'post_reaction' : 1,
})
```

The main difference is that I want to extract the values from the 'actions' column (which is a list of dictionaries) and create separate columns based on the 'action_type' key. How can I achieve this transformation in Pandas?

I tried using pandas' explode method and also tried using loops, all to no avail, with the explode method i was waiting for a value without a list and a dict, but this was not the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a dataframe out of the dict column:

```
df2 = df1['actions'].apply(
    lambda dicts: {d['action_type']: d['value'] for d in dicts}
).apply(pd.Series)
```

This will produce a dataframe with the same index as the original one. Now, just join them together:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```